# how to take user input in a program that run through uninstall script [Linux RPM build]

Tags: bash, ubuntu, redhat, rpm, uninstallation

**Scenario**:
I have an RPM package that I install in Redhat Linux. It is a kind of password-protected program.

so if I uninstall my program with the command `DeepArmor - sudo rpm -e <pacakge-name>` the uninstall script runs in which a separate program run which should take input from the user like password.

**The problem is that on RPM package, user input failed when it prints for the user input, however in Ubuntu DEB package(same code flow) it works just fine.**

the program that runs has all permission like **777**

Getting this Error
[image]

Comment: This is a fundamental design-choice (or limitation) of RPM. See https://serverfault.com/questions/299544/making-a-rpm-package-installation-non-interactive

Comment: Please don't post images of text; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code kind of enables the user input `exec </dev/tty;`
code flow would be

```
if exec </dev/tty; then
   read Input **OR** <call your process which takes input>
fi
```